# Need help to configure network setting for VMware machines

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware

i am using ubuntu 22.04.4 and i have installed vmware for practising purpose. i haveinstalled oracle linux in vm for oracle database. i am not able to connect with vm via ssh through my host machine.

1. Need help with network config to access vm through host machine
2. need to know how to set static ip in ubuntu

Comment: Just set your VM Network setting in VMWare to Bridged instead of NAT.

Comment: tried that also but it's not working.